# Firebase Save Many to Many

Tags: javascript, firebase, ionic-framework, firebase-realtime-database

I am working on an ionic app and there are many to many relationships. My question is:

```
     {
        "name": "jack",
        "students": {
            myid: true,

        }
    }
```

Let's take this example: When I store this in the firebase, myid is taking as "myid" and not the value of the myid. But since myid is variable, I can't put it beforehand.

How can I do this?

Comment: question is unClear, please provide more detail